# SQL-Server Using "USE" with INNER JOINS and "UNION" together

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I've seen plenty of documentation on `UNION` and `INNER JOIN` in the same query, but I cannot find documentation on this specific case.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do, but this syntax is invalid:

```
USE DB1
SELECT DISTINCT ResourceTable.ID, CustomerTable.FN
FROM ResourceTable
INNER JOIN CustomerTable ON ResourceTable.CID = CustomerTable.CID
UNION ALL
USE DB2
SELECT DISTINCT ResourceTable.ID, CustomerTable.FN
FROM ResourceTable
INNER JOIN CustomerTable ON ResourceTable.CID = CustomerTable.CID
ORDER BY ResourceTable.ID
```

So basically, there are two databases that have identical schema but different data. I need to run an `INNER JOIN` query on both of them, and one way I imagined that might work is a `UNION`.

This would all work except for Line 6, where I am attempting to reference another database. I'm wondering if there is a way to make this work and I'm just getting the syntax wrong.

One option would be to insert both into a `##temp` table and then query the temp table, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easy one. Try the code below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ResourceTable.ID, CustomerTable.FN
FROM DB1.dbo.ResourceTable AS ResourceTable 
INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.CustomerTable AS CustomerTable 
ON ResourceTable.CID = CustomerTable.CID
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT ResourceTable.ID, CustomerTable.FN
FROM DB2.DBO.ResourceTable AS ResourceTable 
INNER JOIN DB2.DBO.CustomerTable AS CustomerTable 
ON ResourceTable.CID = CustomerTable.CID
ORDER BY ResourceTable.ID;
```

This is considering that you are using the default schema "dbo" if the tables are under other schema just replace dbo with whatever schema.

This way is very useful to archive data between different DB's, compare data or do whatever join between tables in different DB's.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the databases directly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ResourceTable.ID, CustomerTable.FN 
FROM DB1..ResourceTable 
INNER JOIN DB1..CustomerTable ON ResourceTable.CID = CustomerTable.CID 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT ResourceTable.ID, CustomerTable.FN 
FROM DB2..ResourceTable 
INNER JOIN DB2..CustomerTable ON ResourceTable.CID = CustomerTable.CID
ORDER BY ResourceTable.ID
```

Note you should replace `..` with your schema name, like `.dbo.`.

Comment: Ah, of course! Should've realized. I have 7 joins happening in the actual query so I think this concept flew right over my head. Angel M is also correct, but HoneyBadger was first to respond (if only barely) so answer goes to HoneyBadger.  Thanks!